# If I'll tell you I'll have to kill you, maybe even then not

Tags: halacha, death, lashon-hara-slander

Can one tell Lashon Hara to someone about to die? It won't spread any further. Do poskim discuss this?

Comment: Thanks for the interesting question! Did you mean to include in your question the case that the potential listener's seeming very likely to be about to die, or did you really mean to include only the (extremely rare) case it's known with certainty that he's about to die?

Answer (score 2):

Lashon Hara is forbidden even if the listener utterly rejects the content as entirely false and never repeats it again. The speaker has still transgressed multiple negative commandments.

Certainly spreading it makes it worse, but that is not the only reason it is forbidden.

Comment: Sourcing your first paragraph would make this a stronger answer.